# Multiple inheritance in Javascript with prototype chain

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, multiple-inheritance, prototypal-inheritance

I have a JavaScript MVC design, implemented using prototypes, where different items may be displayed in different ways as decided by the controller. For example an 'Event' item may be displayed with the views `ViewTabs` or `ViewSimple`. Class hierarchy:

```
ViewBase
- ViewTabs 
-- EventViewTabs, which implements EventViewTabs.Validate
- ViewSimple
-- EventViewSimple, which implements EventViewSimple.Validate
```

Deciding whether to use `EventViewTabs` or `EventViewSimple` is done by a `EventController`. My problem is: I have a `Validate` method for checking inputs from the `Event` views, but this method is identical for the `EventViewTabs` and the `EventViewSimple` views. Where should I put `Validate` in order to avoid duplication? I cannot put it in `ViewBase`, as other items (e.g. `User`) also inherit from this class.

Seems I need multiple inheritance for this, but is there a smarter way to do it? I have a feeling I'm overlooking something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your validator could be tailor-made with the type it has to work with. In UML, it's called composition. I figure out your code as follows:

```
function Validator {}
Validator.prototype.validate = function(arg) {
  //arg is no longer inputs
  return true|false; //the ultimate output along with additional information;
}

function EventViewTabsValidator() {}
EventViewTabsValidator.prototype = Object.extend(Validator.prototype); //inheritance
EventViewTabsValidator.prototype.constructor = EventViewTabsValidator; //enforce the constructor to point to your derived type
EventViewTabsValidator.prototype.validate = function() {
  var inputs = $('inputs');
  var param = 'do some stuff specific to EventViewTabsValidator based on the inputs';
  return Validator.prototype.validate.call(this, param); //pass param, not inputs
}

function EventViewSimpleValidator() {} 
EventViewSimpleValidator.prototype = Object.extend(Validator.prototype); //inheritance
EventViewSimpleValidator.prototype.constructor = EventViewSimpleValdiator; //enforce the constructor to point to your derived type
EventViewSimpleValidator.prototype.validate = function() {
  var inputs = $('inputs');
  var param = 'do some stuff specific to EventViewSimpleValidator based on the inputs';
  return Validator.prototype.validate.call(this, param); //pass param, not inputs
}


function EventViewTabs() {
  this.validator = null; //see init
}
EventViewTabs.prototype.init = function() {
  this.validator = new EventViewTabsValidator();
}
function EventViewSimple() {
  this.validator = null; //see init
}
EventViewSimple = function() {
  this.validator = new EventViewSimpleValidator();
}
```

Your could abstract up both types to a base `EventView`, which could expose `this.validator`.
Your instance of `EventController` will call:

```
var simple = new EventViewSimple();
simple.validator.validate();

var tabs = new EventViewTabs();
tabs.validator.validate();
```

Whatever the `EventView` instance, they implement their own specific validator that can be called in a generic way.

Comment: Thanks, seems this was the obvious solution I couldn't figure out for myself!

Answer (score 3):

You're missing *composition*. Inheritance isn't the answer to all issues about code reuse to avoid *copy-paste programming*.

Let's say you've a `View` *base prototype*:

```
function View() { }
```

If you want this view to support validation, you can *inject* the *validation dependency* in the constructor function:

```
function View(validator) {
   this.validator = validator;
}
View.prototype = {}; // A lot of functions here
```

That is, now any view which inherits `View`'s prototype will have an associated validator. In other words: **you don't need to derive two prototypes in your concrete view** (you don't need and you can't do it anyway).

In the other hand, in terms of object-oriented programming, it wouldn't make sense to derive from `Validator` to create a `View`.

When you say *a view has a validator*, since you're using *has*  as verb, you're talking about an association (a form of *composition*). Alternatively,  when you say *my main screen **is** as view*, we're talking about an *inheritance*, **because a specific view must be also a view, so it needs base view's members to act like a view**.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use mixins to add the other behavior (this is the ruby approach, and is also used by react.js and react.rb)  You can google for javascript+mixins and find some excellent tutorials like this one:  http://raganwald.com/2014/04/10/mixins-forwarding-delegation.html

For your specific case `validate` (or perhaps `validator`) would be the mixin.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to do something like this:
ViewBase

```
ViewBase
-EventValidator, which implements  Validate
--ViewTabs
---EventViewTabs
--ViewSimple
---EventViewSimple.
```

Also consider to use composition over inheritance see [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wfMtDGfHWpA)

Comment: I should probably have been more specific: Other classes also inherits from ViewTabs and ViewSimple, so these classes cannot inherit from EventValidator. Thanks for tip on composition though.